# Is it possible to have 2 AWS servers with same Friendly name running in parallel on same environment.

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is it possible to have 2 AWS servers with same Friendly name running in parallel on same environment.  e.g Suppose I have a server in Prod box with friendly name, ZBS_DB01 i need to replicate this server and run ZB_DB01 in parallel, post validation will turn off old server.  Kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If by friendly you mean the Tag "Name=Server Name" i.e. which appears in the AWS EC2 Console showing list of instances, yes it is absolutely possible. The uniqueness of the instance's identity is enforced by instance-id and appropriate reservation-id.

[image]